# How to parse Json data returned from a HTTP request in scala

Tags: json, scala

I am trying to parse JSON data returned from an HTTP request as below.
import scalaj.http.{Http, HttpResponse}

```
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSON
import scalaj.http.{Http, HttpResponse}

object ScalaHttp {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        def get(url: String,i: Int) = Http(url).param("page",i.toString)
        for(i <- 1 to 15 by 1) {
            var jsonFile = get("url",i).asString
            println(jsonFile)
        }
    }
}
```

The data comes in pages so I looped through all the pages manually from 1 to 15 and each page returns one element give below.
When I print the string:L `jsonFile`, I see the string in below format:

```
HttpResponse({"run_sessions":[{"id":9003843,"start_time":"2012-02-22T10:59:06.000Z","end_time":"2012-02-22T11:52:43.000Z","duration":3217769,"distance":13644,"encoded_trace":null,"sport_type_id":3},{"id":9000024,"start_time":"2012-02-22T09:12:51.000Z","end_time":"2012-02-22T18:49:26.000Z","duration":7009,"distance":0,"encoded_trace":null,"sport_type_id":7},{"id":9003605,"start_time":"2012-02-21T12:21:00.000Z","end_time":"2012-02-21T12:43:47.000Z","duration":1367000,"distance":2600,"encoded_trace":"kd}wHuo~n@?fDlCbG?vE{@|GfB|FmAjHzCtIzBmEhAgGcE}DuDyEuE}DaCeEAsHjDSrBnDlBaA_EuGf@aEGjD","sport_type_id":1},{"id":9003604,"start_time":"2012-02-21T12:21:00.000Z","end_time":"2012-02-21T12:44:02.000Z","duration":1382000,"distance":2600,"encoded_trace":"gd}wHiq~n@_@hDvDpGe@nEi@tG~C|FgDtFxCjKvCaB`CqFsEuEgDcFkEsCaCyH{@}D|CmBrBhCxCp@oE}Hb@wEDn@","sport_type_id":1},{"id":9003952,"start_time":"2012-02-21T12:15:00.000Z","end_time":"2012-02-21T12:59:59.000Z","duration":2699120,"distance":6990,"encoded_trace":"ktcsGi~x]{@]rD~@{Jt@k@jI{BfJqJ{a@f@xa@}CmGsHa\\\\KhJsD}CaA}MrO{`@cCrL|Iub@hCsJvAyClB}DxAqD`EtA}End@rCtFdKiQbCdAbDaH~B}FjAlDbGlCvMmCyLf\\\\?nEnAhL{B|H}@hEvWiPqBbEan@|\\\\h@oDqBrCuDgILaHhBeFzGgFxE|@pB|BdBnCl@rC{Bt@qB~BJnG}@tA","sport_type_id":1},{"id":9004251,"start_time":"2012-02-21T12:07:13.000Z","end_time":"2012-02-21T14:38:45.000Z","duration":7820873,"distance":54670,"encoded_trace":"ybtzHqgx_@ifAp}Bw^n}B{Dl{DhBlqDqzCvi@aWdaDtf@~tCru@x~CdL~mExYjuEhoBqNvlC{gAbtA`mAxByyCx@{eFm`@wuF_j@elGiMqeG_k@a{E_y@w`D","sport_type_id":4},{"id":9004249,"start_time":"2012-02-21T12:07:04.000Z","end_time":"2012-02-21T13:41:35.000Z","duration":5676621,"distance":8909,"encoded_trace":"irveHulcvAMP{CzWiGvEyEtCs@uHiDzIqBfH{ErH{ExD{HuBgFvA{Dr@o@jH}D`GqFpE}GeBvAmExBqFjOcBRzDkEvFeH`GgGy@n@iIdEmHtO`@uGxLcL|EaC_GjDkFxMaF`DxDiErGkGhFsFVk@qHxCqF`QaGnHgCfEjAdGB|FoDlDgFbCgIpBcGrBJrArFxAkIhGuCzDa@?yU","sport_type_id":2},{"id":9004252,"start_time":"2012-02-21T12:07:00.000Z","end_time":null,"duration":0,"distance":0,"encoded_trace":null,"sport_type_id":1},{"id":9004245,"start_time":"2012-02-21T12:06:51.000Z","end_time":"2012-02-21T12:39:51.000Z","duration":1760262,"distance":4579,"encoded_trace":"axfvBrsr|Q?GTeCp@_EdBkD|@uD\\\\sDVuA}@`DWpDs@nDiAzCaAvDIn@r@oDhAmDdAsDd@cDb@}CJ_Aq@~Da@`Di@lDyArCq@dDSlBj@iDr@{CzA_Et@cEDaC`AqCeAxC?zBu@pCq@rCsAxCk@rCOfAl@aDbAwDrA_Dp@iDV}CRiAq@|De@rDk@zCkAnC_AhDSdC","sport_type_id":1},{"id":9004243,"start_time":"2012-02-21T12:06:48.000Z","end_time":"2012-02-21T13:05:57.000Z","duration":3547966,"distance":8096,"encoded_trace":"ckrtGs_ew@cZ_R_]gXg\\\\hAaJu@iBwJ_N{OuHuGiE{XKgNlCcLkAhLNbN`Kt_@dQxSnFnMzL}UfOxL`f@da@|VdV??","sport_type_id":1},{"id":9004239,"start_time":"2012-02-21T12:06:48.000Z","end_time":"2012-02-21T14:53:22.000Z","duration":9985106,"distance":13048,"encoded_trace":null,"sport_type_id":2},{"id":9004238,"start_time":"2012-02-21T12:06:47.000Z","end_time":"2012-02-21T12:21:38.000Z","duration":891191,"distance":2721,"encoded_trace":"u{ckGiy`LBHPjBHrBpAxAPnBIdC]xCU`CVpBF~BLnBpArA|ApAjAj@lAn@hBj@~A_@lBKbAmBb@eB?aCEgA}Aw@w@NiA]iAOuAF{Bp@kA`BX|B^~BxAvAxAp@jBi@`@iDb@wCmAs@}AYQaAL{Bd@uBVyCL{CY}AyAAuAKiBs@}AgA}@uAoAcB]g@","sport_type_id":1},{"id":9004232,"start_time":"2012-02-21T12:06:34.000Z","end_time":"2012-02-21T12:08:16.000Z","duration":101937,"distance":845,"encoded_trace":null,"sport_type_id":9},{"id":9004230,"start_time":"2012-02-21T12:06:30.000Z","end_time":null,"duration":0,"distance":0,"encoded_trace":null,"sport_type_id":1},{"id":9004226,"start_time":"2012-02-21T12:06:18.000Z","end_time":null,"duration":0,"distance":0,"encoded_trace":null,"sport_type_id":5}],"meta":{"pagination":{"per_page":15,"available_pages":71,"total":1059,"page":"1","sort_by":"start_time","order":"desc"}}},200,Map(Cache-Control -> Vector(max-age=0, private, must-revalidate), Connection -> Vector(keep-alive), Content-Length -> Vector(3727), Content-Type -> Vector(application/json; charset=utf-8), Date -> Vector(Tue, 01 Oct 2019 11:44:24 GMT), Etag -> Vector("2269df166d2348a8adc43b8170651bc8"), Server -> Vector(WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.3/2014-05-14)), Set-Cookie -> Vector(request_method=GET; path=/), Status -> Vector(HTTP/1.1 200 OK), Via -> Vector(1.1 vegur), X-Content-Type-Options -> Vector(nosniff), X-Frame-Options -> Vector(SAMEORIGIN), X-Request-Id -> Vector(321da733-1172-4547-90a2-42d5d3b027fa), X-Runtime -> Vector(0.068370), X-Ua-Compatible -> Vector(chrome=1), X-Xss-Protection -> Vector(1; mode=block)))
```

Libraries used:

```
name := "ScalaRest"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "2.3.0"
```

It has Maps, Sets in the string which I don't understand how to parse.
From the above string which is in JSON format, how can I parse the data and extract data of the elements: id, starttime, endtime, duration

Comment: What have you tried/code? Which lib do you use?

Comment: Using scalaJ library. I have updated the question with the contents of build.sbt file

Comment: `scala.util.parsing.json` has been deprecated for more than 3 years now _(for very good reasons)_. I would recommend you to use an appropriate library like **Circe**, **json4s**, **play-json**, **uJson**, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [uJson,](http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/HowtoworkwithJSONinScala.html#extracting-values-from-json) which is very fast and intuitive. No need for dedicated classes or implicit parsers. I have used it in multiple projects:

```
val json = ujson.read(Http("my_url").asString.body))
val tuples = json("run_sessions").arr /* <-- run_sessions is an array */ .map { item => 
    (item("id"), item("start_time"), item("end_time"), item("duration")) 
}
```

Comment: +1 hat's a nice solution. You should add the imports and so on. Make a scalafiddle out of it too and show a runnable test version of it :D

Comment: -1 because uJson has not fixed security vulnerability: https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/dbmetd/simple_web_and_api_servers_with_scala/ - much more safer and efficient option would be using of Dijon 0.3.0: https://github.com/pathikrit/dijon

Comment: haha you're ruthless. Would you mind linking what the security issue is? Also if you're going to propose a solution as better, would you mind using the above example and show how it's done using this library? If it's less code and a better solution, it would be nice to see. EDIT: Nevermind, see you wrote an answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Using play.api.libs.json._
You can do it through implicits and case classes

Define the case-class like this:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

 case class Run_sessions(
  id: Double,
  start_time: String,
  end_time: Option[String],
  duration: Double,
  distance: Double,
  encoded_trace: Option[String],
  sport_type_id: Double
)
case class Pagination(
  per_page: Double,
  available_pages: Double,
  total: Double,
  page: String,
  sort_by: String,
  order: String
)
case class MetaBis(
  pagination: Pagination
)
case class RootJsonObject(
  run_sessions: List[Run_sessions],
  meta: MetaBis
)
```

Define some implicit Formats for the case classes:

```
object formatters {
implicit val a: Format[Run_sessions] = Json.format[Run_sessions]
implicit val b: Format[Pagination] = Json.format[Pagination]
implicit val c: Format[MetaBis] = Json.format[MetaBis]
implicit val d: Format[RootJsonObject] = Json.format[RootJsonObject]
}
```

Use validate to create the case-class from the Json

```
val json = Json.parse("""{

  "run_sessions": [
    {
      "id": 9003843,
      "start_time": "2012-02-22T10:59:06.000Z",
      "end_time": "2012-02-22T11:52:43.000Z",
      "duration": 3217769,
      "distance": 13644,
      "encoded_trace": null,
      "sport_type_id": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 9000024,
      "start_time": "2012-02-22T09:12:51.000Z",
      "end_time": "2012-02-22T18:49:26.000Z",
      "duration": 7009,
      "distance": 0,
      "encoded_trace": null,
      "sport_type_id": 7
    },
    {
      "id": 9003605,
      "start_time": "2012-02-21T12:21:00.000Z",
      "end_time": "2012-02-21T12:43:47.000Z",
      "duration": 1367000,
      "distance": 2600,
      "encoded_trace": "kd}wHuo~n@?fDlCbG?vE{@|GfB|FmAjHzCtIzBmEhAgGcE}DuDyEuE}DaCeEAsHjDSrBnDlBaA_EuGf@aEGjD",
      "sport_type_id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 9003604,
      "start_time": "2012-02-21T12:21:00.000Z",
      "end_time": "2012-02-21T12:44:02.000Z",
      "duration": 1382000,
      "distance": 2600,
      "encoded_trace": "gd}wHiq~n@_@hDvDpGe@nEi@tG~C|FgDtFxCjKvCaB`CqFsEuEgDcFkEsCaCyH{@}D|CmBrBhCxCp@oE}Hb@wEDn@",
      "sport_type_id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 9003952,
      "start_time": "2012-02-21T12:15:00.000Z",
      "end_time": "2012-02-21T12:59:59.000Z",
      "duration": 2699120,
      "distance": 6990,
      "encoded_trace": "ktcsGi~x]{@]rD~@{Jt@k@jI{BfJqJ{a@f@xa@}CmGsHa\\\\KhJsD}CaA}MrO{`@cCrL|Iub@hCsJvAyClB}DxAqD`EtA}End@rCtFdKiQbCdAbDaH~B}FjAlDbGlCvMmCyLf\\\\?nEnAhL{B|H}@hEvWiPqBbEan@|\\\\h@oDqBrCuDgILaHhBeFzGgFxE|@pB|BdBnCl@rC{Bt@qB~BJnG}@tA",
      "sport_type_id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 9004251,
      "start_time": "2012-02-21T12:07:13.000Z",
      "end_time": "2012-02-21T14:38:45.000Z",
      "duration": 7820873,
      "distance": 54670,
      "encoded_trace": "ybtzHqgx_@ifAp}Bw^n}B{Dl{DhBlqDqzCvi@aWdaDtf@~tCru@x~CdL~mExYjuEhoBqNvlC{gAbtA`mAxByyCx@{eFm`@wuF_j@elGiMqeG_k@a{E_y@w`D",
      "sport_type_id": 4
    },
    {
      "id": 9004249,
      "start_time": "2012-02-21T12:07:04.000Z",
      "end_time": "2012-02-21T13:41:35.000Z",
      "duration": 5676621,
      "distance": 8909,
      "encoded_trace": "irveHulcvAMP{CzWiGvEyEtCs@uHiDzIqBfH{ErH{ExD{HuBgFvA{Dr@o@jH}D`GqFpE}GeBvAmExBqFjOcBRzDkEvFeH`GgGy@n@iIdEmHtO`@uGxLcL|EaC_GjDkFxMaF`DxDiErGkGhFsFVk@qHxCqF`QaGnHgCfEjAdGB|FoDlDgFbCgIpBcGrBJrArFxAkIhGuCzDa@?yU",
      "sport_type_id": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 9004252,
      "start_time": "2012-02-21T12:07:00.000Z",
      "end_time": null,
      "duration": 0,
      "distance": 0,
      "encoded_trace": null,
      "sport_type_id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 9004245,
      "start_time": "2012-02-21T12:06:51.000Z",
      "end_time": "2012-02-21T12:39:51.000Z",
      "duration": 1760262,
      "distance": 4579,
      "encoded_trace": "axfvBrsr|Q?GTeCp@_EdBkD|@uD\\\\sDVuA}@`DWpDs@nDiAzCaAvDIn@r@oDhAmDdAsDd@cDb@}CJ_Aq@~Da@`Di@lDyArCq@dDSlBj@iDr@{CzA_Et@cEDaC`AqCeAxC?zBu@pCq@rCsAxCk@rCOfAl@aDbAwDrA_Dp@iDV}CRiAq@|De@rDk@zCkAnC_AhDSdC",
      "sport_type_id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 9004243,
      "start_time": "2012-02-21T12:06:48.000Z",
      "end_time": "2012-02-21T13:05:57.000Z",
      "duration": 3547966,
      "distance": 8096,
      "encoded_trace": "ckrtGs_ew@cZ_R_]gXg\\\\hAaJu@iBwJ_N{OuHuGiE{XKgNlCcLkAhLNbN`Kt_@dQxSnFnMzL}UfOxL`f@da@|VdV??",
      "sport_type_id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 9004239,
      "start_time": "2012-02-21T12:06:48.000Z",
      "end_time": "2012-02-21T14:53:22.000Z",
      "duration": 9985106,
      "distance": 13048,
      "encoded_trace": null,
      "sport_type_id": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 9004238,
      "start_time": "2012-02-21T12:06:47.000Z",
      "end_time": "2012-02-21T12:21:38.000Z",
      "duration": 891191,
      "distance": 2721,
      "encoded_trace": "u{ckGiy`LBHPjBHrBpAxAPnBIdC]xCU`CVpBF~BLnBpArA|ApAjAj@lAn@hBj@~A_@lBKbAmBb@eB?aCEgA}Aw@w@NiA]iAOuAF{Bp@kA`BX|B^~BxAvAxAp@jBi@`@iDb@wCmAs@}AYQaAL{Bd@uBVyCL{CY}AyAAuAKiBs@}AgA}@uAoAcB]g@",
      "sport_type_id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 9004232,
      "start_time": "2012-02-21T12:06:34.000Z",
      "end_time": "2012-02-21T12:08:16.000Z",
      "duration": 101937,
      "distance": 845,
      "encoded_trace": null,
      "sport_type_id": 9
    },
    {
      "id": 9004230,
      "start_time": "2012-02-21T12:06:30.000Z",
      "end_time": null,
      "duration": 0,
      "distance": 0,
      "encoded_trace": null,
      "sport_type_id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 9004226,
      "start_time": "2012-02-21T12:06:18.000Z",
      "end_time": null,
      "duration": 0,
      "distance": 0,
      "encoded_trace": null,
      "sport_type_id": 5
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "pagination": {
      "per_page": 15,
      "available_pages": 71,
      "total": 1059,
      "page": "1",
      "sort_by": "start_time",
      "order": "desc"
    }
  }
}""")

  import formatters._
  println(
    json.validate[RootJsonObject]
  )
```

Here's a Scalafiddle with showing how to do it, I added Option's to some fields that are sometimes missing. Hope it helps
https://scalafiddle.io/sf/J5dDfFo/3

Comment: And of course, one your parse it, you can reach the fields inside the json object easily by for example .sport_type.id and so on.

Comment: I also used these websites: https://jsonformatter.org/json-pretty-print and https://json2caseclass.cleverapps.io/

Answer (score -1):

Most safe and efficient way to parse the body of that HTTP response is using of [jsoniter-scala](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala).

1) Add dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter-scala" %% "jsoniter-scala-core"   % "0.55.4" % Compile,
  "com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter-scala" %% "jsoniter-scala-macros" % "0.55.4" % Provided // required only in compile-time
)
```

2) Define data structures, derive codec for the root structure and parse the response body:

```
import java.time.Instant

import com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter_scala.macros._
import com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter_scala.core._

case class Response(
  run_sessions: List[RunSession],
  meta: Meta)

case class RunSession(
  id: Int,
  start_time: Instant,
  end_time: Option[Instant],
  duration: Int,
  distance: Int,
  encoded_trace: Option[String],
  sport_type_id: Int)

case class Meta(pagination: Pagination)

case class Pagination(
  per_page: Int,
  available_pages: Int,
  total: Int,
  @stringified page: Int,
  sort_by: String,
  order: String)

implicit val codec: JsonValueCodec[Response] = JsonCodecMaker.make(CodecMakerConfig())

val body: Array[Byte] = """{"run_sessions":[{"id":9003843,"start_time":"2012-02-22T10:59:06.000Z","end_time":"2012-02-22T11:52:43.000Z","duration":3217769,"distance":13644,"encoded_trace":null,"sport_type_id":3},{"id":9000024,"start_time":"2012-02-22T09:12:51.000Z","end_time":"2012-02-22T18:49:26.000Z","duration":7009,"distance":0,"encoded_trace":null,"sport_type_id":7},{"id":9003605,"start_time":"2012-02-21T12:21:00.000Z","end_time":"2012-02-21T12:43:47.000Z","duration":1367000,"distance":2600,"encoded_trace":"kd}wHuo~n@?fDlCbG?vE{@|GfB|FmAjHzCtIzBmEhAgGcE}DuDyEuE}DaCeEAsHjDSrBnDlBaA_EuGf@aEGjD","sport_type_id":1},{"id":9003604,"start_time":"2012-02-21T12:21:00.000Z","end_time":"2012-02-21T12:44:02.000Z","duration":1382000,"distance":2600,"encoded_trace":"gd}wHiq~n@_@hDvDpGe@nEi@tG~C|FgDtFxCjKvCaB`CqFsEuEgDcFkEsCaCyH{@}D|CmBrBhCxCp@oE}Hb@wEDn@","sport_type_id":1},{"id":9003952,"start_time":"2012-02-21T12:15:00.000Z","end_time":"2012-02-21T12:59:59.000Z","duration":2699120,"distance":6990,"encoded_trace":"ktcsGi~x]{@]rD~@{Jt@k@jI{BfJqJ{a@f@xa@}CmGsHa\\\\KhJsD}CaA}MrO{`@cCrL|Iub@hCsJvAyClB}DxAqD`EtA}End@rCtFdKiQbCdAbDaH~B}FjAlDbGlCvMmCyLf\\\\?nEnAhL{B|H}@hEvWiPqBbEan@|\\\\h@oDqBrCuDgILaHhBeFzGgFxE|@pB|BdBnCl@rC{Bt@qB~BJnG}@tA","sport_type_id":1},{"id":9004251,"start_time":"2012-02-21T12:07:13.000Z","end_time":"2012-02-21T14:38:45.000Z","duration":7820873,"distance":54670,"encoded_trace":"ybtzHqgx_@ifAp}Bw^n}B{Dl{DhBlqDqzCvi@aWdaDtf@~tCru@x~CdL~mExYjuEhoBqNvlC{gAbtA`mAxByyCx@{eFm`@wuF_j@elGiMqeG_k@a{E_y@w`D","sport_type_id":4},{"id":9004249,"start_time":"2012-02-21T12:07:04.000Z","end_time":"2012-02-21T13:41:35.000Z","duration":5676621,"distance":8909,"encoded_trace":"irveHulcvAMP{CzWiGvEyEtCs@uHiDzIqBfH{ErH{ExD{HuBgFvA{Dr@o@jH}D`GqFpE}GeBvAmExBqFjOcBRzDkEvFeH`GgGy@n@iIdEmHtO`@uGxLcL|EaC_GjDkFxMaF`DxDiErGkGhFsFVk@qHxCqF`QaGnHgCfEjAdGB|FoDlDgFbCgIpBcGrBJrArFxAkIhGuCzDa@?yU","sport_type_id":2},{"id":9004252,"start_time":"2012-02-21T12:07:00.000Z","end_time":null,"duration":0,"distance":0,"encoded_trace":null,"sport_type_id":1},{"id":9004245,"start_time":"2012-02-21T12:06:51.000Z","end_time":"2012-02-21T12:39:51.000Z","duration":1760262,"distance":4579,"encoded_trace":"axfvBrsr|Q?GTeCp@_EdBkD|@uD\\\\sDVuA}@`DWpDs@nDiAzCaAvDIn@r@oDhAmDdAsDd@cDb@}CJ_Aq@~Da@`Di@lDyArCq@dDSlBj@iDr@{CzA_Et@cEDaC`AqCeAxC?zBu@pCq@rCsAxCk@rCOfAl@aDbAwDrA_Dp@iDV}CRiAq@|De@rDk@zCkAnC_AhDSdC","sport_type_id":1},{"id":9004243,"start_time":"2012-02-21T12:06:48.000Z","end_time":"2012-02-21T13:05:57.000Z","duration":3547966,"distance":8096,"encoded_trace":"ckrtGs_ew@cZ_R_]gXg\\\\hAaJu@iBwJ_N{OuHuGiE{XKgNlCcLkAhLNbN`Kt_@dQxSnFnMzL}UfOxL`f@da@|VdV??","sport_type_id":1},{"id":9004239,"start_time":"2012-02-21T12:06:48.000Z","end_time":"2012-02-21T14:53:22.000Z","duration":9985106,"distance":13048,"encoded_trace":null,"sport_type_id":2},{"id":9004238,"start_time":"2012-02-21T12:06:47.000Z","end_time":"2012-02-21T12:21:38.000Z","duration":891191,"distance":2721,"encoded_trace":"u{ckGiy`LBHPjBHrBpAxAPnBIdC]xCU`CVpBF~BLnBpArA|ApAjAj@lAn@hBj@~A_@lBKbAmBb@eB?aCEgA}Aw@w@NiA]iAOuAF{Bp@kA`BX|B^~BxAvAxAp@jBi@`@iDb@wCmAs@}AYQaAL{Bd@uBVyCL{CY}AyAAuAKiBs@}AgA}@uAoAcB]g@","sport_type_id":1},{"id":9004232,"start_time":"2012-02-21T12:06:34.000Z","end_time":"2012-02-21T12:08:16.000Z","duration":101937,"distance":845,"encoded_trace":null,"sport_type_id":9},{"id":9004230,"start_time":"2012-02-21T12:06:30.000Z","end_time":null,"duration":0,"distance":0,"encoded_trace":null,"sport_type_id":1},{"id":9004226,"start_time":"2012-02-21T12:06:18.000Z","end_time":null,"duration":0,"distance":0,"encoded_trace":null,"sport_type_id":5}],"meta":{"pagination":{"per_page":15,"available_pages":71,"total":1059,"page":"1","sort_by":"start_time","order":"desc"}}}""".getBytes("UTF-8")
val response: Response = readFromArray(body)
```

3) [Optional] Print the parsed result

```
print(response)

// Response(List(RunSession(9003843,2012-02-22T10:59:06Z,Some(2012-02-22T11:52:43Z),3217769,13644,None,3), RunSession(9000024,2012-02-22T09:12:51Z,Some(2012-02-22T18:49:26Z),7009,0,None,7), RunSession(9003605,2012-02-21T12:21:00Z,Some(2012-02-21T12:43:47Z),1367000,2600,Some(kd}wHuo~n@?fDlCbG?vE{@|GfB|FmAjHzCtIzBmEhAgGcE}DuDyEuE}DaCeEAsHjDSrBnDlBaA_EuGf@aEGjD),1), RunSession(9003604,2012-02-21T12:21:00Z,Some(2012-02-21T12:44:02Z),1382000,2600,Some(gd}wHiq~n@_@hDvDpGe@nEi@tG~C|FgDtFxCjKvCaB`CqFsEuEgDcFkEsCaCyH{@}D|CmBrBhCxCp@oE}Hb@wEDn@),1), RunSession(9003952,2012-02-21T12:15:00Z,Some(2012-02-21T12:59:59Z),2699120,6990,Some(ktcsGi~x]{@]rD~@{Jt@k@jI{BfJqJ{a@f@xa@}CmGsHa\\KhJsD}CaA}MrO{`@cCrL|Iub@hCsJvAyClB}DxAqD`EtA}End@rCtFdKiQbCdAbDaH~B}FjAlDbGlCvMmCyLf\\?nEnAhL{B|H}@hEvWiPqBbEan@|\\h@oDqBrCuDgILaHhBeFzGgFxE|@pB|BdBnCl@rC{Bt@qB~BJnG}@tA),1), RunSession(9004251,2012-02-21T12:07:13Z,Some(2012-02-21T14:38:45Z),7820873,54670,Some(ybtzHqgx_@ifAp}Bw^n}B{Dl{DhBlqDqzCvi@aWdaDtf@~tCru@x~CdL~mExYjuEhoBqNvlC{gAbtA`mAxByyCx@{eFm`@wuF_j@elGiMqeG_k@a{E_y@w`D),4), RunSession(9004249,2012-02-21T12:07:04Z,Some(2012-02-21T13:41:35Z),5676621,8909,Some(irveHulcvAMP{CzWiGvEyEtCs@uHiDzIqBfH{ErH{ExD{HuBgFvA{Dr@o@jH}D`GqFpE}GeBvAmExBqFjOcBRzDkEvFeH`GgGy@n@iIdEmHtO`@uGxLcL|EaC_GjDkFxMaF`DxDiErGkGhFsFVk@qHxCqF`QaGnHgCfEjAdGB|FoDlDgFbCgIpBcGrBJrArFxAkIhGuCzDa@?yU),2), RunSession(9004252,2012-02-21T12:07:00Z,None,0,0,None,1), RunSession(9004245,2012-02-21T12:06:51Z,Some(2012-02-21T12:39:51Z),1760262,4579,Some(axfvBrsr|Q?GTeCp@_EdBkD|@uD\\sDVuA}@`DWpDs@nDiAzCaAvDIn@r@oDhAmDdAsDd@cDb@}CJ_Aq@~Da@`Di@lDyArCq@dDSlBj@iDr@{CzA_Et@cEDaC`AqCeAxC?zBu@pCq@rCsAxCk@rCOfAl@aDbAwDrA_Dp@iDV}CRiAq@|De@rDk@zCkAnC_AhDSdC),1), RunSession(9004243,2012-02-21T12:06:48Z,Some(2012-02-21T13:05:57Z),3547966,8096,Some(ckrtGs_ew@cZ_R_]gXg\\hAaJu@iBwJ_N{OuHuGiE{XKgNlCcLkAhLNbN`Kt_@dQxSnFnMzL}UfOxL`f@da@|VdV??),1), RunSession(9004239,2012-02-21T12:06:48Z,Some(2012-02-21T14:53:22Z),9985106,13048,None,2), RunSession(9004238,2012-02-21T12:06:47Z,Some(2012-02-21T12:21:38Z),891191,2721,Some(u{ckGiy`LBHPjBHrBpAxAPnBIdC]xCU`CVpBF~BLnBpArA|ApAjAj@lAn@hBj@~A_@lBKbAmBb@eB?aCEgA}Aw@w@NiA]iAOuAF{Bp@kA`BX|B^~BxAvAxAp@jBi@`@iDb@wCmAs@}AYQaAL{Bd@uBVyCL{CY}AyAAuAKiBs@}AgA}@uAoAcB]g@),1), RunSession(9004232,2012-02-21T12:06:34Z,Some(2012-02-21T12:08:16Z),101937,845,None,9), RunSession(9004230,2012-02-21T12:06:30Z,None,0,0,None,1), RunSession(9004226,2012-02-21T12:06:18Z,None,0,0,None,5)),Meta(Pagination(15,71,1059,1,start_time,desc)))
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining why this is better or more efficient than using play.api.libs.json._ other than that of course play is super heavy and annoying to import etc.